# wxpython + matplotlib: autoresizing a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, layout, matplotlib, wxpython

This python program plots a figure in a wxpython window.

How can I change the program so that:

- the figure resizes when I resize the window
- the main window cannot be resized smaller than a particular dimension? (say, half the default size of the window)

.

```
# adapted from:
# http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started
# http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/s11/presentations/pearse.pdf

import wx
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class GUIPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # create some sizers
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # A button
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Tada!")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick,self.button)

        # put up a figure
        self.figure = pl.figure()
        self.axes = self.drawplot(self.figure)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)  
    def log(self, fmt, *args):
        print (fmt % args)
    def OnClick(self,event):
        self.log("button clicked, id#%d\n", event.GetId())
    def drawplot(self, fig):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        t = pl.arange(0,1,0.001)
        ax.plot(t,t*t)
        ax.grid()
        return ax

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = GUIPanel(frame)
frame.Fit()
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: does this change in light of your other question?

Comment: no. [GRATUITOUS USELESS WORDS TO FILL UP CHARACTERS]

Answer (score 2):

1) Modify the way you setup your sizer to this:

```
sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
```

Here is [method reference](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html#Add). It is also helpful to install and use [wxPython Demo](http://wxpython.org/download.php). Sizers are covered nicely there. BTW: `wx.ALL` is useless unless you specify border.

---

2) And add this to your frame setup after `frame.Show()`:

```
size = frame.GetSize()
frame.SetMinSize((size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2))
```